# Mod 5 producing different answers in PHP & JS, sometimes both wrong

Tags: javascript, php, modulo

So, I have my code on here, it's for a math question I was challenged to answer, but I can't get it to work.

Both the PHP and JS code have the same logic, but are producing different answers.

http://dev.mattcowley.co.uk/main/dev/PRIVATE/Posers32/Q3.php

Scripts listed at bottom of page, question at the top.

The Question:
    If n is any integer chosen randomly from 1 to 100, what is the probability that 1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n is exactly divisible by 5?

The Logic:
    Loop through array of 1 to 100, calculate 1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n, mod 5 it, and if that is 0, add 1 to counter

The PHP:

```
#Range 1 - 100 Generated for testing
$nL = range(1, 100);
$m5 = 0;

foreach ($nL as $n) {
    $nS = pow(1, $n) + pow(2, $n) + pow(3, $n) + pow(4, $n);
    $nM = $nS % 5;
    if ($nM == 0) {
        $m5 += 1;
    }

    echo "n: ".$n."<br/>";
    echo "n Sum: ".$nS."<br/>";
    echo "n Mod5: ".$nM."<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
}

echo "<br/>Total Mod5 = 0 Count: ".$m5;
echo "<br/>Probability: ".(($m5/count($nL))*100)."%";

?>
```

The JS:

```
//Range 1 - 100 Generated for testing
var nL = Array.apply(null, Array(101)).map(function (_, i) {return i;}); nL.shift();
var m5 = 0;

for (index = 0; index < nL.length; ++index) {
    var n = nL[index];
    var nS = Math.pow(1, n) + Math.pow(2, n) + Math.pow(3, n) + Math.pow(4, n);
    var nM = nS % 5;
    if (nM == 0) {
        m5 += 1;
    }

    document.write("n: "+n+"<br/>");
    document.write("n Sum: "+nS+"<br/>");
    document.write("n Mod5: "+nM+"<br/>");
    document.write("<br/>");
}

document.write("<br/>Total Mod5 = 0 Count: "+m5);
document.write("<br/>Probability: "+((m5/nL.length)*100)+"%");

</script>
```

Please Help <3

Comment: Can include text of `js` , `php` tried at Question ? _"it's for a math question I was challenged to answer"_ Can describe "math question" ?,  expected result ?

Comment: Discrepancies start to appear at n = 16

Comment: The script is listed at the bottom of the page, I don't know the expected result, hence the experiment, but I was at least expecting that to be the same.

Comment: It's almost certainly because of number precision. Above a certain, albeit large, integer value, both PHP and Javascript are going to lose precision.

The PHP setting (for 5.0.5 and later) can be found with PHP_INT_MAX

Comment: `4338079554 / 5 = 867615910.8` , `867615910.8 % 5 = 0.7999999523162842`

Comment: @guest271314 Its mod, not divide. (https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=4338079554%20%25%205)

Comment: @P.Gearman Yeah that probably is the issue actually, hadn't thought of that, thanks!

Comment: @MatthewCowley `%` is actually "remainder" at `js` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Comment: I will say that there is a mathematical solution to this problem that does not involve large numbers. It just requires that you recognize the patterns. (I swear, I'm not trolling.)

Comment: `4338079554` is not "exactly divisible by 5"

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, thats what modulo is basically -.-
Hence on the documentation you linked it says _"It uses a built-in modulo function to produce the result, which is the integer remainder of dividing var1 by var2"_

Comment: @P.Gearman You're probably right, I'm just lazy I guess, and so turned to code.